# How to make specific mobs in Minecraft make no sound

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

In my regular Minecraft survival world (1.17.30), I want to know if there is a way to make only certain mobs make no sound or only some sounds.

Example 1: A creeper would not hiss when charging but would still make a boom sound when exploding.

Example 2: A pig never oinks but a chicken still clucks.

Comment: One approach would be to use the regular modding techniques to replace those sound files with empty sounds.

Comment: Maybe the `Silent` tag is what you are searching for? Add it to a mob and it will be completely silent. Not tested with the creeper explosion

Comment: The "silent" tag is a mod or plugin, it is not in vanilla Minecraft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to achieve this in vanilla Minecraft would be to use a texture pack that replaces the .ogg sound files of the noises you want to silence with empty sound files so that you cannot hear them.

Comment: Note that this wouldn't affect closed captioning.

Comment: Some texture packs appear to rewrite the closed captions, perhaps they could be left as empty strings?